# ArgumentOutOfRangeException at Calling Index

Tags: c#, indexing, substring

I got a really annoying error.

My following code is what I have (the same worked 1 hour before)

```
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dir + fileDAT))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line.Substring(0,5) == "\tVNUM\t")
                {
                    vnum = Convert.ToInt32(line.Substring(6));
                    Console.ReadLine(); 
                    Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.
                }

            }
        }
```

But now it throws at line `if (line.Substring(0,5) == "\tVNUM\t")` an ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Do you know how to fix this? And how much indexes does "\t" have?

Comment: What is the value of line when there is an exception?   That will show you what is wrong.

Comment: It was "\tVNUM\t0" .. But now it works. See below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the `line` is less than 5 chars long.
Replace your `if` with the following:

```
if (line.Length >= 5 && line.Substring(0,5) == "\tVNUM\t")
```

The `\t` char is a char, so it has length `1` char.

By the way, are you sure you really need to read lines twice per each iteration? I mean the following code portion:

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)  // 1st read
{
    line = reader.ReadLine();  // 2nd read
```

**EDIT**
The string `"\tVNUM\t"` is `6` chars long, you know. It doesn't make any sense to compare it to the 5-chars length substring.

Comment: Thank you for answering. string line is 7 chars long, but if I replace my code with yours, it only skips the procedure..

Comment: Yes. You're right. Its redundant, but I have only placed it two times to test it

Comment: It's because the string `"\tVNUM\t"` is `6` chars long.

Comment: Ah, yes. But the line which is read is 7 chars long ("\tVNUM\t0") But I think after pasting your code and playing a bit with the indexes it works now.

Comment: Just replace `5` with the `6` in the `if` to compare 6 chars.

Comment: Yes this was my second fault. Thank you for helping!